# What should be the db structure for a friend/buddy system

Tags: database-design

I am building a friend/buddy system, where one user can send friend requests, accept, reject, or block someone.

Initially I was using a simple two column table:

```
user (BIGINT)
friend (BIGINT)
```

The idea was that if `user1` had a friend `user2` then there would be two rows where in one of them `user1` would be `user2`'s friend, and in another row, just the opposite, meaning they are mutual friends. On the other hand, if there was only one such row, it would mean, the other user is yet to accept the user as a friend.

However, this structure doesn't seem to handle `rejected` or `blocked` statuses, so I was wondering what would be a better db structure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have the following structure:

```
User
 id    name

Status
 id    name

Frienship
 idUser    idUserFriend   idStatus
  ^Fk to user               ^fk to status
              ^FK to user
```

This model will handle your problem just fine.